# How to set images id dynamically in integer array

Tags: android

Here is my code, I have 100 images and i want to create it dynamic using loop but it's not working.

```
   int[] imgIds = {R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3};
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing? What is not working? Your question states a loop but there is no loop in the code snippet that you posted

Comment: What problem you are facing ? also share code which you have tried

Comment: I am just asking how to create it dynamically.this is just simple and i don't want to write 100 images name in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `getResources().getIdentifier` to create array of drawable id's if drawables name is as img1,img2,img3,..

```
int[] imgIds = new int [100];
int imagecount=1;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
imgIds[i]=getResources().getIdentifier("img"+imagecount,
                                           "drawable", getPackageName());
imagecount++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your images are all called with the same prefix and the only thing it does change is the number you can do the following thing:

Suppose you numbered from `0` to `size -1`

```
ArrayList<Integer> imgIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  imgIds.add(getResources().getIdentifier("img"+i, "drawable", getPackageName());
}
```

check for typo.
Edit. With array:

```
int[] imgIds = new int[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  imgIds[i] = getResources().getIdentifier("img"+i, "drawable", getPackageName();
}
```

Comment: I want to implement it using array not array list.

Comment: When I am trying to put your  code but it gives error "null pointer"
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  int mGalleryItemBackground;
  private Context mContext;
                ArrayList<Integer> mImageIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {mImageIds.add(getResources().getIdentifier("img"+i, "drawable", getPackageName());
  }
}

Comment: where do you get the NPE? post the stacktrace